# Can Dired (or Dired+) detect symlinks in Windows?

Tags: dired, microsoft-windows, symbolic-links

Can Dired(+) be made to show symlinks in Windows?

A picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: Windows file explorer shows symlinks, Dired does'nt.]